# How to allow select-and-typeover on a field that limits characters via keypress listener

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I've used a keypress listener to force a field to only accept numbers--and only two numbers at that. The problem is that it prevents the user from typing two numbers, selecting the numbers, and typing over them.

Here's the JavaScript that I used to limit the keypress:

```
// Only allow 2 numeric characters
jQuery('input').on('keypress', function(e){

    console.log( e.which);

    // Only allow numbers
    var is_number = /[0-9]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which));

    // Or special characters
    var is_special_key = ( e.metaKey || // cmd/ctrl
        e.which <= 0 || // arrow keys
        e.which == 8 ); // backspace

    return ( is_special_key || ( is_number && ($(this).val()).length < 2 ) );
});
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/pL0ctwka/1/

How can I allow users to select and type over?

Comment: You should consider also users pasting numbers with more than 2 characters

Comment: Hi. It's possible and easy way, **however**, you can use a **keyboard delimiter plugin** made by me, this works for this issue. I hope that will be usefull for you. You can find this in https://github.com/ameliandev/KeyboardDelimiter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
// Only allow 2 numeric characters
jQuery('input').on('keypress', function(e){

    console.log( e.which);

    // Only allow numbers
    var is_number = /[0-9]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which));

    // Or special characters
    var is_special_key = ( e.metaKey || // cmd/ctrl
        e.which <= 0 || // arrow keys
        e.which == 8 ); // backspace

    return ( is_special_key || ( is_number && (( $(this).val( ) ).length < 2 || (this.selectionEnd - this.selectionStart ) ) > 0 ) );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pL0ctwka/2/